# How do I identify the different stages of meiosis under microscope?

Tags: microscopy, meiosis

This is a question I'm troubled with as my exams are knocking at the door. I need help so I decided to post this here.

Here's what I know and understand about meiotic stages:

Specimen: Grasshopper (*Gesonula punctifrons*) testis whose 2n= 23

**Note:** The character in bold and italics is the identifying feature of the concerned stage.

**Prophase:**

***Leptotene***

- The uncondensed chromosomes are visible as a cloud of thin threads.
- Each chromosome consist of two chromatids which are not visible.
- ***The single darkly stained X chromosome is found at the periphery of the nucleus.***
- Late in this stage the chromosomes attach themselves by telomeres to the inner membrane of the nuclear envelope forming a bouquet.
- Nuceolus and nuclear membrane are present.(not visible under compound 
  microscope)

***Zygotene***

- The uncondensed chromosomes are visible as a cloud of threads.
- Homologous chromosomes undergo synapsis  forming bivalent.
- ***The single darkly stained X chromosome is present slightly off the periphery of the nucleus.***
- Nucleolus and nuclear membrane are present.(not visible)

***Pachytene***

- The chromosomes show some degree of condensation.
- The sister chromatids separate to form tetrad a structure with four chromatids.
- Crossing over between non sister chromatids of homologous chromosomes occur leading to ***formation of X shaped chiasmata***.
- Nucleolus and nuclear membrane are present.(not visible)

***Diplotene***

- The chromosomes are thick and darkly stained.
- ***The chromosomes are wooly in appearance.***
- The paired chromosomes separate from each other except for the chiasmata.
- Nucleolus and nuclear membrane begin to diappear.(can't be detected)

***Diakinesis***

- The chromosomes are thick and darkly stained.
- Terminalisation of chiasmata initiates.
- ***The bivalents appear rod, diamond or oval shaped.***
- The nucleus and nuclear membrane disappear completely.

***Metaphase-I***

- The chromosomes are thick and darkly stained.
- Presence of twelve chromosomal elements (11 tetrad + X chromosome).
- ***The chromosomes are aligned at the equitorial plate.***
- Terminalisation of chiasmata completes.

***Anaphase-I***

- ***Two groups of chromosome are in the act of separation.***
- One group is with 11 autosomes and the other group with 11 autosomes and a X chromosome.
- ***The chromosomes are T or V shaped.***
- Each chromosome is in dyad state.
- The centromere is undivided.

***Metaphase-II***

- There is 11-12 dyads present.
- The chromosomes are thick and darkly stained.
- ***The dyads are arranged in circle or flower like fashion.***
- The chromosomes are rod like

***Anaphase-II***

- The sister chromatids of a dyad separate due to splitting of centromere.
- ***Two groups of chromosome are in the act of separation.***
- One group is with 11 autosomes and the other group with 11 autosomes and a X chromosome.
- ***The chromosomes are rod like***

Here's an image which has nearly all the stages except telophase.Can someone label the stages?

[image: Image 1]

Here's what I feel about them:
[image: Image 2]

**Finally** am I correct? How do I identify them correctly? Could you site some authentic references?

Answer (score 4):

ID characteristics that can help you recognize diplotene  better:

**diplotene** : 
the only difference between this phase and Diakinesis is that The centrosomes reach the poles.

you can see the photos of diplotene and diakinesis here :

http://www1.biologie.uni-hamburg.de/b-online/e09/meiosea.htm

[image: diplotene]
[image: Diakinesis]

[image: (a) polyploid nutri-tive cells with many heteropicnotic chromatin bodies; (b) leptotene-zygotene; (c) pachytene; (d) diffuse stage; (e) di-plotene; (f) diakinesis; (g) metaphase I; (h, i) anaphase I; (j) telophase I;. (k) metaphase II; (l) anaphase II; (m) telophase II; (n) round spermatids; (o) elongating spermatids; (p) head of sper-matozoas. Big arrows indicate sex chromosomes, small arrows point to nucleoli and arrowheads indicate m-chromosomes]

(a) polyploid nutri-tive cells with many heteropicnotic chromatin bodies; (b) leptotene-zygotene; (c) pachytene; (d) diffuse stage; (e) di-plotene; (f) diakinesis; (g) metaphase I; (h, i) anaphase I; (j) telophase I;. (k) metaphase II; (l) anaphase II; (m) telophase II; (n) round spermatids; (o) elongating spermatids; (p) head of sper-matozoas. Big arrows indicate sex chromosomes, small arrows point to nucleoli and arrowheads indicate m-chromosomes

You can see all the phases clear and perfectly separated here :

http://biology.about.com/od/meiosis/ss/meiosisstep.htm#step1

by the way , try to adjust microscope as best as you can & don't put much  oil immersion .

Comment: long answer for this Question ?! there is no other thing to explain .
Sanjukta Ghosh asks how to identify different phases of meiosis under microscope and I provided a link that show all 10 phases perfectly clear . I could upload every single photo by my self on the answer if you are asking for it   . why should I put some additional content and confuse the questioner ?

Comment: The images you have linked are not light microscopic views. They are far too clear for light microscope. Besides it lacks the substages of prophase I. I was also looking for an answer that specifies the key identifying characters. It will be helpful if you could improve the answer. Moreover I have attached an unedited image of meiotic stages. Could you label the stages there and explain how you are identifying them.

Comment: They are light microscopic view of course the background is white for better contrast they've been coloring very good and adjust very well . that's how it's gonna be in the exams as far as I've seen . but don worry I will improve the answer by specifying the key id characters . but you should know it's a tricky skill some times no one can say what the phase is as it is really unclear  ... these cases are not gonna be on the exams or so .